# iptables SNAT limit to specific network

Tags: linux, iptables, routing

I have one problem which I cannot resolve as I frankly don't know how, I haven't used iptables quite often....

I have one main linux router which is representing gateway for the internet access and which is passing traffic from (WAN IP) 123.123.123.0/30 -> to 234.234.234.0/23 (internal) network.  Inside that internal network 234.234.234.0 there is another linux router which is having 3 interfaces. For clarification lets say: 234.234.234.254/23 eth0, 192.168.1.1/24 eth1, and 172.16.0.1/24 eth2. So the schematic would look like:

WAN:123.123.123.2 (eth0) -> (eth1) LAN:234.234.234.1/23 // (eth2) LAN:234.234.234.2 -> (eth0) LAN:192.168.0.1/24  and (eth1) LAN:172.16.0.1/24

Obviously, only route that is needed to be set is default route on main router 0.0.0.0  0.0.0.0 via 123.123.123.1/30 (interface which is ISP gateway)

I have set SNAT from both eth0 and eth1 or should I say (192.168.1.0/24 and 172.16.0.0/24) to go out via 234.234.234.254/23 eth2

Example:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 234.234.234.2
```

Now all traffic from both private networks are going out via 234.234.234.254 and that is fine. I have internet access which I wanted, but problem is that from private networks I can also reach 234.234.234.0/23 network, which I don't want. I would like to isolate whole traffic to go outside only, but not be able to reach any of machines  in network 234.234.234.0/23

How can I achieve that?

What rules are missing to limit traffic to go out, or should I say to allow "internet" access only, but not the "intranet" (of the network 234.234.234.0/23)...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packets are evaluated against rules in `filter/FORWARD` before `nat/POSTROUTING` as seen [in this Netfilter schematic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg), so `FORWARD` can still see unmodified source IP addresses. There is thus no complication or special settings to consider, not even NAT. The firewall rules to add on the second router are simply:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 234.234.234.0/23 -j REJECT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 172.16.0.0/24 -d 234.234.234.0/23 -j REJECT
```

There are probably many variations to consider, which are possible here. E.g. you can replace `-s 192.168.1.0/24` with `-i eth0` and `-s 172.16.0.0/24` with `-i eth1`.

The reverse direction happens to be "protected" by NAT. You should anyway add more rules to enforce it (and protect private networks from the internal network), but then you'd better consider a real set of stateful rules anyway, which can track opened flows, and would then simplify the case where you'd wish to grant some exceptions between private networks and internal network for some sources or destinations. Please check further various [examples](https://reggle.wordpress.com/2015/07/12/linux-iptables-part-i-basic-rules/) [using](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-examples.html) [stateful](http://fibrevillage.com/sysadmin/199-linux-iptables-connection-tracking-configuration) [firewalling](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Iptables#Stateful_firewall), or simply search for "stateful iptables" (note that in those examples the [`state`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#state) module is now superseded by the [`conntrack`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#conntrack) module).

Comment: Thnx man. In regards to your answer: Yes, I know that FORWARD is done before POSTROUTING chain (at least I saw it from graphics while Google-ing about iptables), but for some stupid reason I have set forward rule for 192.168.1.0/24 (internal network) to destination 234.234.234.0/23 to ALLOW instead of REJECT or DROP and set chain by default to DROP. Not sure where I got that bright idea... :D Anyway, thanks man. cheers